# Linux Image to recreate a machine with the same configuration

Tags: linux, centos-6

I have a CentOS 6.5 machine with some installed packages , I want three more identical boxes to be setup and I was wondering if I can make an image of the one machine that I have pre-configured and use that image to make copies of that one machine onto other machines.

This would save me a lot of time, please let me know if this is possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can use tools like CloneZilla to create a bit-for-bit copy, but there are hassles / caveats to doing so.  Examples of things that you *want* to be different between the machines:

- Hostname
- IP address
- SSH, SSL, and any other public key cryptography private keys.
- UUIDs

For CentOS / RedHat systems, there is a configuration file called a 'kickstart' file that can be used to create a set of instructions for the installation process.  The configuration instructions to produce the system you just installed is probably located in your root user's home directory.

These instructions are in a kickstart file (ending in .ks if I recall correctly) in the root user's home directory, and will produce another system configured exactly as the current system was immediately after it finishes booting for the first time after install.

The process for doing kickstart installs is a little involved (more involved than CloneZilla), but will avoid the issues listed above.

Comment: Thanks @Slartibartfast , can kickstart process be used to install packages like MongoDB , Tomcat etc ?